# In PowerPoint 2007 how do I write a code to invoke an existing macro by pressing a set of keys?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I wrote a macro in PowerPoint 2007 but am having trouble assigning the macro a keyboard shortcut, how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You need an add-in like this one:

http://officeone.mvps.org/ppsctmgr/ppsctmgr_macros.html

But if an add-in isn't suitable for you and you're only developing on the PC version of PowerPoint then you could try using Windows APIs to add timers and key trapping. These APIs will get you started:

```
Public Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal vkey As Long) As Integer
Public Declare Function GetKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal nVirtKey As Long) As Integer
Public Declare Function SetTimer Lib "user32" _
            (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
            ByVal nIDEvent As Long, _
            ByVal uElapse As Long, _
            ByVal lpTimerFunc As Long) As Long

Public Declare Function KillTimer Lib "user32" _
            (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
            ByVal nIDEvent As Long) As Long
```

Comment: I'm a beginner, sorry, how do I set up the API?